# Is there an out-of-the-box way to configure user-submitted content?

Tags: joomla-3.x, content

I remember that long long ago there was an extension called JA submit that let users create unpublished Joomla articles, that I could then go into Joomla, edit, and approve.

I would essentially want to setup a similar editorial pipeline for user-contributed content.

Is there a way to do this now that Joomla has access levels?, or should I create my own component?

Comment: Hi Duke, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 2):

**For Registered Users** :

If you want the registered users to submit "Articles" then all you have to do is to create a new menu item -> Select Type -> Articles -> Create Article and set the access to **Registered**

**For Public Users** :

If you want the public users to submit "Articles" then you have to give this permission to the "Public" user group. Go to **Content** -> **Article Manager** -> **Options** -> **Permissions** select the public tab and change the "Create" setting to **Allowed**

You can configure which category you want the users to submit their articles in from the category permissions tab.

Answer (score 1):

Article Access Levels:
Goto backend -> Content -> Article manager -> Options -> Permissions -> Here, you can set the access levels for example public user access which of the things simular to all.